# Bootstrap Carousel - Issues when split & show four images per slide.

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi I have used bootstrap Carousel for display the images. I wanted to show only four images per slide. But Here, since these images are coming dynamically through loop, i couldn't move the images to next slide. I tried slice() and wrapAll() methods but i didn't get the desired result & i have no idea whether this approach is right or wrong. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance. **Note:** Please see the fiddle in full screen.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/paperindex-home.css">
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/js/paperindex-home.min.js">
</script>
<div class="our-partners-wrap hidden-xs">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="text-center section-heading">Our Partners</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
          <!-- Carousel items -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
              <div class="row justify">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://expogr.com/ethiopia/pppexpo/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.tissueworld.com/miami" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/Tissue_World_Miami-300x250.png" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/kenyappp/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 kenya.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/tanzania/pppexpo/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 tanzania.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/tanzania/pppexpo/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 tanzania.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/tanzania/pppexpo/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 tanzania.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/tanzania/pppexpo/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 tanzania.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/tanzania/pppexpo/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 tanzania.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="http://www.expogr.com/tanzania/pppexpo/index.php&#10;" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/300x250 tanzania.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                  <a href="&#9;&#10;http://www.expogr.com/kenyappp/index.php" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/&#9;&#10;300x250 kenya.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- row-1 -->
            </div>
            <!--.item-->
          </div>
          <!--.carousel-inner-->
          <div class="pi-carousel-controls hidden-xs visible-md-up">
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa  fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa  fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--.Carousel-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--.container-fluid-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/paperindex-home.css">
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/js/paperindex-home.min.js">
</script>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <h3>Partners</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have shown the images statically. But, in my case i have shown all the images in one item :)

Comment: Is that a requirement? Because this shows 4 images in one page